# XAMPP pointing a file outside root folder

Tags: apache, apache2, xampp, localhost, document-root

I am using XAMPP for first time in Mac. Running out problems accessing other than root folder(htdocs).when I am placing my web application inside htdocs with default httpd.conf file it works when I try to point my web application url in httpd.conf it throws **`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`** error

I am aware that to modify the root folder I need to do changes to my XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file

With Default XAMPP MAC Settings, I am trying to change Server root,Document root and Directory in XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file the following

```
ServerRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles"

DocumentRoot "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate"

<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was chmod problem. I tried giving chmod -r 777 to Development folder, backbone folder and Backboneboilerplate.. It worked.